# Can't remove the default padding on the button

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a button which doesn't have any padding defaultly. I have tried using `minWidth` and `minHeight` but I couldn't make it work.

This is the activity_main.xml code.

```
<android.widget.RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.dijitalbeyin.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:background="#A3ADDE" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="İsminiz:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTxt_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_name"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editTxt_name"
    android:minWidth="0dp" />

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

This is the preview of the activity_main.xml file.
[image: activity_main.xml preview]

What should I do ?

Comment: That padding is part of the `Button` background.

Comment: Set a custom background drawable .and provide size to button .